# Read child node along with its parent attribute from XML in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

I have an XML similar to this structure.

```
<Root>
<id>a2bh5</id>
<Student ID="123">
    <Name>abc<Name>
    <course>ETL<course>
    <Scores>
        <Score>
            <Subject>SSIS<subject>
            <grade>B<grade>
        </score>
        <Score>
            <Subject>Informatica<subject>
            <grade>C<grade>
        </score>
    </Scores>
</Student>
<Student ID="456">
    <Name>xyz<Name>
    <course>ETL<course>
    <Scores>
        <Score>
            <Subject>Pentaho<subject>
            <grade>F<grade>
        </score>
        <Score>
            <Subject>Datastage<subject>
            <grade>A<grade>
        </score>
    </Scores>
</Student>
</Root>
```

I would like to get details from child nodes(scores) along with its parent attribute(Id) using Xquery in SQL server.

The query result is expected like below for all subjects. Please help.

```
Student_Id subject grade
========================
123     SSIS        B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your sample XML is cleaned up and all tags are properly closed, try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Root>
<id>a2bh5</id>
<Student ID="123">
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <course>ETL</course>
    <Scores>
        <Score>
            <Subject>SSIS</Subject>
            <grade>B</grade>
        </Score>
        <Score>
            <Subject>Informatica</Subject>
            <grade>C</grade>
        </Score>
    </Scores>
</Student>
<Student ID="456">
    <Name>xyz</Name>
    <course>ETL</course>
    <Scores>
        <Score>
            <Subject>Pentaho</Subject>
            <grade>F</grade>
        </Score>
        <Score>
            <Subject>Datastage</Subject>
            <grade>A</grade>
        </Score>
    </Scores>
</Student>
</Root>'

SELECT
    StudentID = XStudents.value('@ID', 'int'),
    Course = XStudents.value('(course)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Subject = XScore.value('(Subject)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Grade = XScore.value('(grade)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM
    @Input.nodes('/Root/Student') AS XT1(XStudents)
CROSS APPLY
    XStudents.nodes('Scores/Score') AS XT2(XScore)
```

This gives an output of:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to fix your XML. Your `Name`, `course`, `Subject`, and `grade` elements don't have proper closing tags. Also, element names are case-sensitive in XML; `Subject` and `subject` are not the same thing.

Once you've done that, you can use the [`nodes()` method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to break the XML into rows and then extract the data you want. Like so:

```
declare @test xml = 
    '<Root>
    <id>a2bh5</id>
    <Student ID="123">
        <Name>abc</Name>
        <course>ETL</course>
        <Scores>
            <Score>
                <Subject>SSIS</Subject>
                <grade>B</grade>
            </Score>
            <Score>
                <Subject>Informatica</Subject>
                <grade>C</grade>
            </Score>
        </Scores>
    </Student>
    <Student ID="456">
        <Name>xyz</Name>
        <course>ETL</course>
        <Scores>
            <Score>
                <Subject>Pentaho</Subject>
                <grade>F</grade>
            </Score>
            <Score>
                <Subject>Datastage</Subject>
                <grade>A</grade>
            </Score>
        </Scores>
    </Student>
    </Root>';

select
    [Student ID] = N.x.value('(../../@ID)[1]', 'bigint'),
    [Subject] = N.x.value('(./Subject)[1]', 'varchar(64)'),
    [Grade] = N.x.value('(./grade)[1]', 'char(1)')
from
    @test.nodes('/Root/Student/Scores/Score') N(x)
```

Results:

```
Student ID   Subject       Grade
---------------------------------
123          SSIS          B
123          Informatica   C
456          Pentaho       F
456          Datastage     A
```